# "Often" usage in places

Tags: word-usage

"I often go to Paris" could mean that you go twice a year, however, you wouldn't use "I often go to the dentist" even though you have your teeth checked twice a year." Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether one uses often can be relative to how often a normal person does it. Normal people don't travel abroad twice a year, but everybody (should) go to the dentist twice a year.

Normal people don't say `I go to school often`, unless they think of school as a waste of time, going twice a week.

**TLDR:** It's relative based on the person and the action.

Answer (score 0):

The adverb *often* belongs to a class of words called [Adverbs of Frequency](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adverb/adverbs-frequency/) (like *daily*, *weekly*, *yearly*, *sometimes*, and *rarely*), words which indicate how frequently something happens. Words like *daily* describe DEFINITE frequency and are considered **Adverbs of Definite Frequency**, whereas words like *often* convey only an approximate or INDEFINITE idea of frequency and are therefore considered **Adverbs of Indefinite Frequency**.

Examples of Adverbs of Definite Frequency:

• Hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly

• Every second, once a minute, twice a year

• Once, twice, once or twice, three times

Adverbs of Definite Frequency, like all adverbs of DEFINITE time, typically occupy the END position of a sentence structure:

Examples:

• Most citizens pay their taxes yearly.

• The janitor cleans the toilets every hour.

• The administrators meet weekly to review student progress.

Sometimes, for emphasis or style, Adverbs of Definite Frequency occupy the FRONT of a sentence structure:

• Every day, more than five thousand people die in our post offices.

Adverbs of Indefinite Frequency occupy MID position in sentence structures, i.e., before the main verb (except the main verb "*to be*"):

• We usually go to the mall on Saturday.

• I have often wanted to be a bird.

• She is always well-dressed and punctual.

Occasionally, *sometimes*, *often*, *frequently* and *usually* occupy the beginning or end of a sentence structure:

• Sometimes they disappear for a few weeks.

• He plays the bon vivant occasionally.

*Rarely* and *seldom* can also occupy the end of a sentence structure (often with "*very*"):

• We attend the opera house rarely.

• Tom eats sushi very seldom.

http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adverb/adverbs-frequency/